# Iterating over a file with re.search() and incrementing dictionary value with each match

Tags: python, regex, dictionary

I am trying to iterate over a file that is written in multiple languages and each time I get a match for a sentence, I want to increment the value of the corresponding dictionary key. Each sentence has a language marker at the beginning (something like lang="de").

```
import re
import sys


lang_freq = {'de':0, 'fr':0, 'it':0, 'rm': 0, 'en': 0, 'ch-de': 0}
word_freq_de = {}

filename = sys.argv[1]
infile = open(filename, "r")


for line in infile:
    matches = re.search(r'\blang=\".*\"\B', line)
    if matches == 'lang="de"':
        lang_freq['de'] +=1
    if matches == 'lang="fr"':
        lang_freq['fr'] +=1
    if matches == 'lang="it"':
        lang_freq['it'] +=1
    if matches == 'lang="rm"':
        lang_freq['rm'] +=1
    if matches == 'lang="en"':
        lang_freq['en'] +=1
    if matches == 'lang="ch-de"':
        lang_freq['ch-de'] +=1

print(lang_freq)
```

Now the dictionary values remain unchanged and I can't figure out where my logic went wrong here. Is it even possible to use the == in this case or would I have to solve it completely differently? I was able to do it without using the re.search method but would still like to solve it like this :)

Comment: `matches` is a match data object. You need `if matches.group() == ...`

Comment: It seems you want `matches = re.search(r'\blang="(.*?)"', line)` and then `if matches: lang_freq[matches.group(1)] +=1`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew 's comment turns 6 `if`s into one.

Answer (score 0):

The [`re.search` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.search) returns a [match object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#match-objects), and when you check for equality with `if matches == 'lang="de"':`, you always get `False`.

You need to compare the match object [`group()` property](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.Match.group), or, better, just *capture* the data in between the double quotes, and then check if it is present in the `lang_freq` dictionary, and then act accordingly.

It seems you just can fix the problem if you use

```py
matches = re.search(r'\blang="(.*?)"', line)
if matches:
    lang_freq[matches.group(1)] +=1
```

Also, see another [example Python code](https://ideone.com/3unJQO):

```py
import re, sys

lang_freq = {'de':0, 'fr':0, 'it':0, 'rm': 0, 'en': 0, 'ch-de': 0}

# filename = sys.argv[1]
# open(filename, "r")
infile = iter('lang="de"\nlang="it"\nlang="de"\nlang="de"\nlang="it"\nlang="pl'.splitlines())

for line in infile:
    matches = re.search(r'\blang="([^"]*)"', line)
    if matches:
        if matches.group(1) in lang_freq:
            lang_freq[matches.group(1)] += 1
        else:
            lang_freq[matches.group(1)] = 1

print(lang_freq)
```

Output:

```
{'de': 3, 'fr': 0, 'it': 2, 'rm': 0, 'en': 0, 'ch-de': 0}
```

Comment: This worked like a charm, thank you so much! I had tried it with the matches.group() before but it always returned an error, I think I placed it in the wrong spot.